# Lift: How to pass data from JavaScript back to the server

Tags: javascript, scala, lift

**What I have so far:**

I'm currently working on a Lift-based project for work. Within the "Browse" section of our site, we have a list of links that cause a "Details" pane to update to display the contents of that link (and Frames are out of the question). The links are generated by

```
<li>{SHtml.a(() => {currentItem.set(itemID); Noop}, itemShortText)}</li>
```

My task is to make it seem like clicking these links changes the page without actually reloading the page. For example, you start out at `/browse`, then click a link numbered `123`. I'm using [History.js](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/history-js) to change the displayed URL to `browse/123`. The idea is that the URL displayed is a permalink: I use URL rewriting of the form

```
LiftRules.statelessRewrite.append {
  case RewriteRequest(ParsePath("browse" :: id :: Nil, _, _, _),_,_) =>
    RewriteResponse("browse"::Nil, Map("id"->id))
}
```

so that users can bookmark the page and come back later without having to click a link from the browse page.

**What's missing:**

This is all well and good, but I run into trouble when using the Back and Forward buttons to navigate around the history. The URL properly displays the address that I visited, but the contents of the details area doesn't update. I have a JavaScript function that looks for an `onpopstate` event:

```
window.onpopstate = function(event){
  if(event.state){
    //this triggers when you navigate back and forward, except when navigating
    //back to the initial page (/browse)
    //figure out the id from the event.state
    alert("popped to id " + id);
    //Want to pass this id back to the server somehow
  } else {
    //this triggers on a normal page load, or when you navigate via a link
    alert("popped with 'false' state");
  }
}
```

In the case that event.state is not false, I figure out the id of the item that the page should show. Now what I want to do is send that id back to the server somehow so that the Lift side of things can update the page accordingly. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**tl;dr** - How can I pass a variable generated in JavaScript back to the Lift side of things for later use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option to call server via AJAX, pass some JSON data as parameters and make server invoke your callback is to use *JsonHandler* class as shown in [Demo Lift Web App](http://demo.liftweb.net/json_more).

Here is the [source code](https://github.com/lift/lift/blob/c0f7509109f279d66a8de04768da01646fa08fad/examples/example/src/main/scala/net/liftweb/example/snippet/AllJson.scala)

Comment: This works well and seems much cleaner. The fact that it was showcased on the Demos page is pretty encouraging too.

Answer (score 1):

I use this helper method:

```
def ajaxLink(in: NodeSeq, clientSideQuery: JsExp, serverAction: String => JsCmd) =
  <a href="javascript://" onclick={
    JsRaw(ajaxCall(clientSideQuery, serverAction)._2.toJsCmd + "; return false;")
  }>{ in }</a>
```

where `clientSideQuery` can be, e.g., a function call: `Call("someJSFunction")`. But I'm a Lift newbie, so feel free to leave this question open until someone more knowledgeable gives their input.

Comment: Looking at the docs for ajaxCall makes me think that this will work. I'll try this out and get back to you about it. Thanks!

Comment: Well, it does work for me at least — but I'm wondering if this is the most idiomatic way to do it in Lift.

Comment: I don't know if it's the *proper* way to do it, but it works for me, so I'm accepting your answer.